# How to get text to align to the start position of a centered video?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to embed YouTube videos on a page, and I would like those videos to be centered. Below each video, I have a text citation to the corresponding video, and I'm struggling to find a way to get this text to align with the start of the embedded video.

So a video, then directly below it, the source text that aligns with the video's start position.

My current implementation positions the text to the start of the `col` div, but this is the closest I could come. I tried implementing `d-inline-flex` to make the box conform to the embedded video, but with that, for some reason, I lost centering. I'm unsure how to get `d-inline-flex` to work in concert with everything else. Any advice is appreciated.

I'm using Bootstrap 5 via jsdelivr CDN. FWIW, the videos are fixed-sized, 520x350.

```
    <div class="row">
        {% for block in page.youtube_embeds %}
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    {{ self.youtube_link }}
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                    <span class="text-muted mb-2">
                        Source: <a href="{{ self.source_url }}">{{ self.source_name }}</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```